# How do I pass AJAX JSONP data into a function?

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I asked a similar question already, but I discovered that I needed to use AJAX and JSONP, which opened up a whole new world of hurt.

A company that I am working with has an API for their Privacy Policy and Terms of Use. I need to create two different pages:

- Privacy Policy
- Terms of Use

So basically I need to search the data that I get from them, find the correct term in "tags" ('ext_privacy' and 'ext_member_terms', respectively), and then use the HTML code from that array for the rest of the page.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to pass that data from AJAX to the function, and even at that point, I don't know how to drill down into the sections appropriately - I thought it would be *external.data.results.tags*, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's my site code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <title>Privacy Policy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data">
    </div>
    <script>

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://guywhogeeks.com/test/test.json',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: 'true',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: dataFeed
        });

        function dataFeed(external) {

            //Establishing htmlString - testing to see if function even fires
            var htmlString = "Hello, world!";

            //I know this is WAY off - I wanted to add the HTML to htmlString
            /*$(external.data.results.tags).find(privacy).each(function() {

                $({
                    text : external.data.results.html
                }).appendTo(htmlString)

            });*/

            $('#data').html(htmlString);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the (slightly modified) JSON - also hosted [here](http://guywhogeeks.com/test/test.json):

```
{"code":200,"status":"Ok","data":
    {"offset":0,"limit":20,"total":2,"target":"html_page","results":[
        {
            "id":"6",
            "title":"Privacy Policy",
            "description":"Privacy Policy",
            "html":"<div class=\"right-rail\">\r\n<div class=\"module\">\r\n<h2 class=\"episode-guide-header\">Web Site Privacy Policy<\/h2>\r\n<div class=\"module-body corp-home-top\">\r\n<div class=\"corp-home-wrapper privacy\">\r\n<\/div>\r\n<!--corp-home-wrapper--><\/div>\r\n<!--module-body corp-home-top-->\r\n<div class=\"module-shadow\">&#160;<\/div>\r\n<\/div>\r\n<!--module--><\/div>\r\n<!--right-rail-->",
            "tags":[
                "ext_privacy"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"66",
            "title":"License and TOU",
            "description":"License Agreement and Terms of Use",
            "html":"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n        <title>License Agreement and Terms of Use<\/title>\r\n    <\/head>\r\n    <body>\r\n       <div class=\"right-rail\">\r\n<div class=\"module\">\r\n<h2 class=\"episode-guide-header\"> License Agreement and Terms of Use<\/h2>\r\n<\/div><\/body>\r\n<\/html>",
            "tags":[
                "ext_member_terms"
            ]
        }
    ]}
}
```

I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

You JSONP payload is incorrect. Your server should return a call to the "callback" function... in your example, the server should return:

```
jsonCallback(
{"code":200,"status":"Ok","data":
    {"offset":0,"limit":20,"total":2,"target":"html_page","results":[
        {
            "id":"6",
            "title":"Privacy Policy",
            "description":"Privacy Policy",
            "html":"<div class=\"right-rail\">\r\n<div class=\"module\">\r\n<h2 class=\"episode-guide-header\">Web Site Privacy Policy<\/h2>\r\n<div class=\"module-body corp-home-top\">\r\n<div class=\"corp-home-wrapper privacy\">\r\n<\/div>\r\n<!--corp-home-wrapper--><\/div>\r\n<!--module-body corp-home-top-->\r\n<div class=\"module-shadow\">&#160;<\/div>\r\n<\/div>\r\n<!--module--><\/div>\r\n<!--right-rail-->",
            "tags":[
                "ext_privacy"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"66",
            "title":"License and TOU",
            "description":"License Agreement and Terms of Use",
            "html":"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n        <title>License Agreement and Terms of Use<\/title>\r\n    <\/head>\r\n    <body>\r\n       <div class=\"right-rail\">\r\n<div class=\"module\">\r\n<h2 class=\"episode-guide-header\"> License Agreement and Terms of Use<\/h2>\r\n<\/div><\/body>\r\n<\/html>",
            "tags":[
                "ext_member_terms"
            ]
        }
    ]}
});
```

In your client, you should define "jsonCallback" like:

```
jsonCallback(data) {
// data is a regular javascript object at this point
// so you can access 'data.data.results[0].html' without a problem
}
```

Check this for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't actually have access to that JSON data.  I just copied and pasted the data that I received and hosted it myself.

Comment: In that case I would create a Proxy service in your own server that calls the external web service and in your page, use this "local" web service as a regular JSON (no need of JSONP because it is not longer a cross domain call). The first part of this page gives you more info about proxy services. http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html